# Арифметические операции в Bash скрипте

Tags: bash, операторы

Учу Bash и пытался реализовать программу, вот ее суть: на ввод подаются 2 числа в диапазоне [-100: 100], после чего считаются их сумма, разность,произведение и частное.
частное вычисляется в том числе дробное, с точностью до 2 знаков после запятой

получилось вот такое:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
x=$1
y=$2
if [[ "$x" -ge "-100" ]] && [[ "$x" -le "100" ]] && [[ "$y" -ge "-100" ]] && [[ "$y" -le "100" ]]; then
    a=$(($x + $y))
    b=$(($x - $y))
    c=$(($x * $y)) 
    if [[ "$x" -eq "0" ]] && [[ "$y" -ne "0" ]]; then
        d="0.00"
    elif [[ "$y" -eq "0" ]]; then
        d="#"
    elif [[ "$c" -eq "$y" ]] && [[ "$c" -gt "1" ]]; then
        d+="0.$(( ($x%$y)*100/$b ))"
    elif [[ "$c" -eq "$-y" ]] && [[ "$c" -lt "1" ]]; then
        d+="-0.$(( ($x%$y)*-100/$b ))"
    elif [[ "$c" -eq "$y" ]] && [[ "$c" -lt "-1" ]]; then
        d+="-0.$(( ($x%$y)*-100/$b ))"
    else
        d=$(bc<<<"scale=2;$x/$y")
    fi
    echo "$a $b $c $d"
fi
```

но в терминале выдает ошибку:

> line 5: + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")

Comment: Внутри `$(( ))` переменные используются по имени: `$((x+y))`

Comment: @PakUula, только первая без $, остальные могут быть вначале представлены значениями перед вычислениями.

Comment: @0andriy наверное, всё зависит от версии. У меня bash 4.4.20 поддерживает все варианты: `echo $(( x + y )) $(($x+$y)) $(($x+y)) $((x+$y))` печаиатает `3 3 3 3`. Я в своём комментарии написал только один вариант, так как такой вариант ARITMETIC EXPANSION работает в старых версиях